# Socket Programming

Tags: java, sockets

I have two program written in two different java file 1.Client code 2.Server code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Destination extends JFrame
{
    JLabel l1;
    JTextArea ta;
    Container cnt;
    DatagramSocket ds;

    Destination() throws Exception
    {
        l1 = new JLabel("Received Message  :");
        ta = new JTextArea(10, 25);
        cnt = getContentPane();
        cnt.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        cnt.add(l1);
        cnt.add(ta);
        setSize(400, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(2);
        setVisible(true);
        ds = new DatagramSocket(210);
    }

    void dispMsg() throws Exception
    {
        while (true)
        {
            byte b[] = new byte[50];
            ds.receive(new DatagramPacket(b, 0, b.length));
            String msg = new String(b, 0, b.length);
            msg = msg.trim();
            ta.append(msg + "\n");
            if (msg.equals("bye"))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String ar[]) throws Exception
    {
        (new Destination()).dispMsg();
    }
}
```

2.Server side

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class Source extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JLabel l1;
    JTextField t1;
    JButton btn;
    Container cnt;
    DatagramSocket ds;

    Source() throws Exception
    {
        l1 = new JLabel("Enter Message");
        t1 = new JTextField(20);
        btn = new JButton("Send Message");
        btn.addActionListener(this);
        cnt = getContentPane();
        cnt.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        cnt.add(l1);
        cnt.add(t1);
        cnt.add(btn);
        setSize(400, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(2);
        setVisible(true);
        ds = new DatagramSocket(210);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        try
        {
            ds.send(new DatagramPacket(t1.getText().getBytes(), 0, t1.getText().length(),
                    InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 211));
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e1, "Error", 0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String ar[]) throws Exception
    {
        new Source();
    }
}
```

I want to run the two program through cmd,which one should i run first and when i run the first code the cmd gets disabled and does not allows me to run the second code, Suggest me how can i run the two program

Comment: You could open two command shells and run one program in each of those.

Comment: Your code ignores all Swing threading rules and basic threading rules and will block the main thread (the reason for your command shell freeze). You will want to read up on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). Use a SwingWorker.

Comment: You've also got your concept of "server" and "client" reversed. The code sending data to the waiting resource is the client (what you have named server), and the thing sitting patiently waiting for network data is the server (what you've name client).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

*Your port numbers are different in server and client. 211,210 choose one!
Your programs will run but client wont be able to connect to server and receive messages.*

ds = new DatagramSocket(`210`);

ds.send(new DatagramPacket(t1.getText().getBytes(),0,t1.getText().length(),InetAddress.getLocalHost(),`211`));

---

> which one should i run first

server code

> how can i run the two program

use 2 different cmd(s)

```
Steps:
```

1. Open one cmd
2. Run srever code
3. open another cmd
4. Run client code

Output and running ref :

[image: Output and running ref]

Comment: ds=new DatagramSocket(211);

 ds.send(new DatagramPacket(t1.getText().getBytes(),0,t1.getText().length(),InetAddress.getLocalHost(),211));

I have change the port number but it's showing an error as Cannot bind.What to do next

Comment: Like you can see in the image attached, the program ran successfully after making that change. Did you recompile the source after changing it(sometimes we miss that part :) )?

Comment: I have re-complied the Source.java file by making the changes in the port no. as 211.I have made no changes to the Destination.java file.I ran the Destination.java file and then the Source.java file but it's showing the same error

Comment: Run source.java then destination.java

Comment: Try running cmds with admin rights. with `Run As Administrator` option.